# Set project icon to all form icon

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Is there something integrated in vs 2008 to set my project icon to all my form without have to set it manually one form at a time?

I'm currently using [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29923/Assigning-an-application-s-icon-to-all-forms-in-th?msg=3691135#xx3691135xx) but I find it a bit over kill to import a dll juste to do that... Basically I import the dll and add this line 
            `this.Icon = Cliver.IconRoutines.HostIcon;` in all form load and this import the project icon and set it to my form icon

Anyway to do this easier with something built in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any option within VS to do it but a simple workaround would be to create an `IconForm` class which inherits from `Form` and then have all your forms inherit from `IconForm` instead.

In project properties, go to `Application`, and change the `Icon and Manifest's Icon` property to the icon you want to use. Then create the base class that will use this icon and have your forms inherit from it.

```
public class IconForm : Form
{
    public IconForm()
    {
        this.Icon = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(Application.ExecutablePath);
    }
}
```

Then replace `Form` with `IconForm` in your forms

```
public partial class Form1 : IconForm 
{ 
    //... 
}
```

Comment: how would this react to form created with the dessigner?

Comment: Since you're inheriting from `Form` and not changing anything major it should work as normal. Of course, you can test it first but it should work like standard forms.

Comment: For those that might be interessed. I tested it out with a test project and it appear to work.